# Can you add language tags to software built in a specific language for greater exposure?

Tags: discussion

I was recently cleaning up some questions based on Phing which is an Apache Ant clone written in PHP. I was told not to add the PHP tag to these questions which I can kind of understand as you can use Phing without actually writing any PHP code. Is there a policy that says you shouldn't add tags to software package questions that are written in a specific language if that package doesn't require you to write your code in that language?

Some points:

- Even though the Phing build files, like Ant, are written in XML, the
  underlying code and tasks system are written in PHP. You often write
  PHP code when working with Phing tasks.
- As Phing is written in PHP, its behaviour is inherited from PHP. Therefore a lot of the questions asked about Phing are actually about how PHP operates in certain situations even though the end user may be working in XML.
- Phing questions tend to get very few hits if they're not tagged with
  PHP as it's only really PHP devs that use the software. I thought
  this would enable Phing questions to gain more exposure. Is this
  considered an incorrect way to tag (gaming the system)?
- At what point does a language tag cease to be relevant to a question? If a language is not cited in a question but the question is obviously based on that language where should you draw the line when tagging? Eg. Phing questions may only contain XML code snippets but PHP is often at the core of the question.

Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the language[s] used in the question and anticipate what language[s] will be used in the answer. If either include a particular language, it would be reasonable to tag the question with that language.

If we were to use the points in your post as a set of categories:

- **“You often write PHP code when working with Phing tasks.”** If PHP code would be appropriate to answer the question, or the question is about PHP when integrated with Phing, the question should be tagged with both [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phing).
- **“As Phing is written in PHP, its behaviour is inherited from PHP.”** [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) should probably *not* be included unless it is known ahead of time that the behavior is caused by PHP semantics. If the person who asks the question knows *a priori* that it is going to involve PHP semantics, they may be able to reduce the question to a pure-PHP question, and then it could be posted with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and *not* [phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phing). But if they ask it believing it is about Phing semantics but just happens to involve PHP under the hood, it should probably be left with just [phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phing), omitting [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

  I’m sort of on the edge of whether it should later be retagged if it so happens that it is PHP behavior. Trying to think of precedent, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809) was later retagged with [branch-prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch-prediction) once it was determined that the problem was caused by it, though it wasn’t tagged that at the start. On the other hand, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534) wasn’t retagged with [denormal-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denormal-numbers)—but then again, that tag doesn’t exist (though it could!).
- **“Phing questions tend to get very few hits”** If it’s a pure-Phing question and has nothing to do with PHP, then yes, tagging it with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) is inappropriate.

In general, if the subject behind some tag depends on a subject in another tag, that alone is not enough to include the latter tag. If so, all [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), and a myriad of other languages would probably also be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), which I’m sure you can see would not be useful. Instead, we only include tags if they are directly used by the question or presumed answers.